# User name is not being echoed

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I made a link on a view on the CodeIgniter framework but the name of the user profile is not being echoed on the view. The link does work though.

```
<?php foreach($userdetail_list as $row){ ?>
<tr>
    <td>
        <a href="<?php echo base_url() . 'User/userdetails/'.$row['user_id']?>">
          <?php echo $row['name']; ?>
        </a>
    </td>
    <td>
        <?php echo $row['email'];?>
    </td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
```

As you guys can see I'm making a link to the user profile with using the user_id but I'm also trying to echo the name of the user profile and that should be the link where someone could click on. Now there is a link to the user profile but its blank and it's not the name of the user.

Does someone know what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

printing userdetail list:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [user_id] => 6
        [email] => jeremy2@gmail.com
        [voornaam] => Jeremy
        [product_id] => 73
        [category_id] => 3
        [product_naam] => Tennisracket
    )
    [1] => Array (
        [user_id] => 4
        [email] => jeremy@gmail.com
        [name] => Jeremy
        [product_id] => 74
        [category_id] => 1
        [product_naam] => testcadeau
    )
)
```

getdata model function:

```
 function getdata($user_id){
  $this->db->select("*"); 
  $this->db->from('users');
  $this->db->where('user_id', $user_id);
  $query = $this->db->get();
  return $query->result();
 }
```

Controller function:

```
public function userdetails($user_id)
 {
  //load the User_model
  $this->load->model('User_model');

  //call function getdata in de Product_model
  $data['userdetail_list'] = $this->User_model->getdata($user_id);

  //laad view
  $data['main_content'] = 'profiel_user';
  $this->load->view('profiel_user',$data);
 }
```

Comment: Sure `name` is the right attribute name? Also, sure you get all the data from the database, and not only the ID? I can't really see something wrong else here... Does the e-mail get echoed?

Comment: Try doing print_r($userdetail_list) and check what data are you getting, you will get an idea.

Comment: Is `email` and `user_id` working OK? Are you sure `name` was part of the data? Have you `var_dump()`ed $row?

Comment: Like the others above have commented. We cannot help you unless we know what the data of the array is. Try die(var_dump($userdetail_list)); before your foreach statement or die(var_dump($row)); inside it, and update your question with the content of your array.

Comment: Yes email does get echoed , And when I print:  <?php  print_r($userdetail_list) ?> it does show name in there..

Comment: 'name' may be case sensitive have you checked that?

Comment: edited my question

Comment: Nope, no capitals in 'name'

Comment: @JohnDoe122 So I see "name" in the second array element, but no "name" in the first one

Comment: Why do you have `voornaam` in one and `name` in the other? Is the name not appearing for _either_ of them, or only user 6?

Comment: Also the email gets echoed twice which is really weird..

Comment: Please post your modal function for getting data.

Comment: actually name = voornaam in dutch i just translated for you guys

Comment: In this case, please don't translate variable/property names in the code for our sake, @JohnDoe122 :) It can be a red herring when fixing code issues.

Comment: Ok, I added getdata function in my question,

Comment: If the model really returns `$query->result();` the view should be using object syntax, not array syntax. i.e. `<?php echo $row->name; ?>`

Comment: /Getting this error when I try this code <?php echo $row->name; >?     : A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Trying to get property of non-object

Filename: views/details.php

Line Number: 39

Backtrace:

File: /home/ubuntu/workspace/application/views/details.php
Line: 39
Function: _error_handler

File: /home/ubuntu/workspace/application/controllers/Product.php
Line: 28
Function: view

File: /home/ubuntu/workspace/index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once

Comment: Based on that error message the model code you show is not the real code. The last line of the function is probably `return $query->result_array();`

Comment: No this is my model code:  function getdata($user_id){
  $this->db->select("*"); 
  $this->db->from('users');
  $this->db->where('user_id', $user_id);
  $query = $this->db->get();
  return $query->result();
 }

Comment: should i change it to return $query->result_array();      ?

Comment: The error message and the printing userdetail list indicate that `$userdetail_list` is an array of arrays which is what `result_array()` returns. Are you sure `$userdetail_list` is set using the function `getdata($user_id)`?

Comment: Yes sir, Ill add my controller function to my question to show you

Comment: How can a function in controller such as this produce a list of users, I mean more than one (if you are providing a user ID to your function)

`$data['userdetail_list'] = $this->User_model->getdata($user_id);`

It should - and must - return only one user. Right?

Comment: The `function getdata($user_id)` you show us cannot produce the array you share as "printing userdetail list:"  `getdata($user_id)` should only produce output where the `user_id` value is the same. Yet your array print shows two different values for user_id.

Comment: Yes I only want it to show the value of one user and not all users, how can I do that?

Comment: I changed it to this: function getdata($user_id){
   $q = $this->db->get_where('users', array('user_id' => $user_id), 1);  
        if($this->db->affected_rows() > 0){
            $row = $q->row();
            return $row;
        }else{
            error_log('no user found getUserInfo('.$user_id.')');
            return false;
        }
 }  is this better?

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46560272/echoing-user-information-not-working-in-codeigniter