# echoing user information not working in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

Hello guys I'm making application on the codeigniter framework and I'm trying to echo user info of a specific user but its not really working. The name is not being echoed. Also all the emails of the users in my database are being echoed.

( The link to the right tuser profile works though but the name of the link doesn't. Its a blank link.
This is my view file:

```
 foreach($userdetail_list as $row): ?>
<tr>
    <td>
        <a href="<?php echo base_url() . 'User/userdetails/'.$row['user_id']?>">
          <?php echo $row['voornaam']; ?>
        </a>
    </td>
    <td>
        <?php echo $row['email'];?>
    </td>
</tr>
<?php endforeach;  ?>
```

My model file:

```
function getdata($user_id){
  $this->db->select("*"); 
  $this->db->from('users');
  $this->db->where('user_id', $user_id);
  $query = $this->db->get();
  return $query->result();
 }

    public function getUserInfo($user_id) {
        $arrReturn = array();
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('users');
        $this->db->where('user_id', $user_id);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        $result = $query->result_array();
        if (!empty($result)) {
            $arrReturn = $result[0];
        }
        return $arrReturn;
    }
```

My controller file:

```
public function userdetails($user_id)
 {
  //load the User_model
  $this->load->model('User_model');

  //call function getdata in de Product_model
  $data['userdetail_list'] = $this->User_model->getdata($user_id);

  $data['user'] = $this->User_model->getUserInfo($user_id);

  //laad view
  $data['main_content'] = 'profiel_user';
  $data['main_content'] = 'details';
  $this->load->view('profiel_user',$data);
 }
```

So basically on the view file, I only want 1 email being echoed of 1 specific user with using the user_id and not all the user emails, also I want to see the name on the view page which is not being echoed and its a blank link. name = voornaam

Comment: Are you trying to get multiple users infos in a list?

Comment: no only 1 user of the user_id

Comment: Possible duplicate of [User name is not being echoed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46545629/user-name-is-not-being-echoed)

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

Model function

```
// Gets a list of multiple users.
function getdata(){
    $query = $this->db->get('users');
    return $query->result_array();
}

// Gets the users information 
public function getUserInfo($user_id) {
    $this->db->where('user_id', $user_id);
    $query = $this->db->get('users');
    return $query->row_array();
}
```

Controller multiple users

```
public function userdetails($user_id) {

    $this->load->model('user_model');

    $data['userdetail_list'] = $this->user_model->getdata();

    $this->load->view('profiel_user', $data);

}
```

View multiple users list

```
<?php foreach($userdetail_list as $row){ ?>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a href="<?php echo base_url('user/userdetails/'.$row['user_id']);?>">
              <?php echo $row['voornaam']; ?>
            </a>
        </td>
        <td>
            <?php echo $row['email'];?>
        </td>
    </tr>
<?php }  ?>
```

Or get single user data

```
public function userdetails($user_id) {

    $this->load->model('user_model');

    $user_info = $this->user_model->getUserInfo($user_id);

    $data['user_id'] = $user_info['user_id'];

    $data['username'] = $user_info['username'];

    $this->load->view('profiel_user', $data);

}
```

View

Or for single user option

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url('user/userdetails/' . $user_id);?>"><?php echo $username;?></a>
```

Comment: controller function should be named userdetails and not index right?

Comment: Name it what ever you need

Comment: You may need to set some routes in config/routes.php explained here http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html#examples The index function you can rename it to what ever you need just a example

Comment: `$route['user/userdetails/(:any)'] = 'user/userdetails/$1;` Not sure what at your end I am guessing

Comment: Where do I put this line: $route['user/userdetails/(:any)'] = 'user/userdetails/$1; in the routes.php file?

Comment: Ok, I put this line  $route['user/userdetails/(:any)'] = 'user/userdetails/$1; in the routes.php file and getting this error sir: Severity: Parsing Error

Message: syntax error, unexpected ''user/userdetails/$1;' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE)

Filename: config/routes.php

Comment: There is just typo a quote missing after 1 `$route['user/userdetails/(:any)'] = 'user/userdetails/$1';`

Comment: Now when I click on the button link the page doesn't load and I see this url: https://kadokado-ferran10.c9users.io//Product/details/%3Cdiv%20style= and not the supposed user id

Comment: Sorry can't help you any further